# How to handle Cocoa application termination properly?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, terminate, nsapplication, nsapplication-delegate

So, here's my case :

I'm developing a NON-standard document-based application and I want to handle the scenario of aborting the termination when there still are unsaved changes in any of the documents.

**My initial idea is :**

- User tries to quit the application (either through the `"Quit XXXXX"` menu item or by clicking the `"X"` button)
- Are there any modified documents?
- if NO : quit
- if YES : notify user that there are unmodified documents. if he wants to proceed, then quit. Else cancel termination.

So, I decided to do it the delegate-way.

**In my Application delegate**, I've implemented :

- `-windowToClose:` (triggered on `NSWindowWillCloseNotification`)
- `applicationShouldTerminate:`
- `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:`

Now, that's what I'm thinking. In the `applicationShouldTerminate:` method :

- Return `NSTerminateNow` if no modified documents exist
- Return `NSTerminateCancel` if there ARE modified documents. In that case, pop up an alert sheet or something like that and if user confirms he wants to quit, then call a `[NSApp terminate:nil];`

Is that the right way to go about it?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's indeed how to do it. But in your `applicationShouldTerminate` implementation, you should just pop up the alert right there, and return `NSTerminateNow` if the user didn't click Cancel; `NSTerminateCancel` otherwise. No need to manually terminate the application later.

Edit: to show an alert as a sheet but run it as a modal dialog, call `beginSheetModalForWindow` on the alert, then call `[NSApp runModalForWindow:alert]`. In addition, in the end selector that you pass for `beginSheetModalForWindow`, you need to call `[NSApp stopModal]` to get out of the modal loop.

However, it is better in this case to run the alert as a sheet for the window, and return `NSTerminateLater` in your `applicationShouldTerminate` implementation. Then, in the end selector for the alert, call `[NSApp replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:]`. This is how Apple recommends you implement this.

Comment: Nice idea; however, here's the code I'm using for the YES-NO alert sheet (http://snippet.mx/Ra8E). How could I do it so that it returns within the same function?